# Get Directions change language

Tags: wordpress, api, google-maps, plugins

I'm working on a Wordpress site that uses the plugin [Get Directions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/get-directions/).
It works properly and gives me the directions in English, but I want to recieve them in Dutch.

I've tried changing the URL from `maps.google.com` to alternatives like `maps.google.nl` and `maps.google.com?language=nl-nl`

Does anyone know how I can get the directions in Dutch? I have also asked on the official Wordpress forums but I don't know how long it usually takes for them to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Seems impossible. The plugin [uses the API URL `http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/get-directions/tags/1.22/get-directions.php#L116). And checking the documentation, there is a `locale` parameter for the [**`/directions`**](http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/) Web Service, but nothing like this exist for the [**`/geocoding`**](http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/) Web Service, which is the one the plugin uses.

Note that the standard locale codes are in the format `language_COUNTRY`, eg, `nl_NL`. I tried to modify the plugin code adding `&locale=nl_NL`(and other languages), but it made no difference.